# I want to timeout a waiting query in oracle

Tags: oracle, timeout

It happens when we extract data from oracle database 11g/12c that the table we are extracting from is busy for hours (i.e there is an exclusive lock already taken over it so we can't extract data). We don't want to wait in the parallel queue forever.. In the same time we want that extracting query to take the full time it needs to extract data (it can take hours in extraction given that there is actual extraction is taking place, not that we are waiting for other queries to finish). Is there an oracle property to do so?

In other words, I want something like setting wait_timeout property in mysql: https://askubuntu.com/a/892859/765684

Thank you.

Comment: In Oracle, locks never prevent data from being read, so I'm not sure I understand what is blocking your extract process.  Is your extract process trying to write something and that write is being blocked?  Have you built some custom locking mechanism via `dbms_lock`?

Comment: Thanks @JustinCave In the extraction process is that we read from an oracle data source (we don't write to that database) meanwhile, there is another process that is updating the data in the table we want to read/extract, in this case the later process will be taking exclusive lock over the table, right? We keep waiting for very long time until this lock is released and we be able to extract data. No custom locking.

Comment: Writers never block readers in Oracle.  It would be very, very unusual to have a process take an exclusive lock on a table-- it would require an explicit `LOCK TABLE table_name IN EXCLUSIVE MODE` call.  And even then it wouldn't block readers.  Are you speculating that you're dealing with a locking issue?  Or are you actually seeing your session in `v$session` with `blocking_session` populated indicating that it is actually blocked?